# Nesting fragment within Jetpack Compose ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-jetpack-compose

I am creating a screen using compose. I have an existing fragment that I am trying to include within my composable using AndroidViewBinding.

I am trying to nest this AndroidViewBinding in a composable ConstraintLayout. The issue I am having is that the fragment appears on top of the other composables and it is not respecting the constraints I pass to it via the modifier.

Does anyone know how I can constrain this AndroidViewBinding to other composables within the ConstraintLayout?

This is what I've tried.

```
@Composable
fun Screen() {
    ConstraintLayout(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        val (section1, section2, fragmentIWantToAdd) = createRefs()
        Section1(
            modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(section1) {
                    top.linkTo(parent.top)
                    start.linkTo(parent.start, margin = 16.dp)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end, margin = 16.dp)
                },
            title = "Section1")
        Section2(
            modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(section2) {
                    top.linkTo(section1.bottom, margin = 16.dp)
                    start.linkTo(parent.start, margin = 16.dp)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end, margin = 16.dp)
                }
        )
        AndroidViewBinding(
            FragmentIWantToAddContainerBinding::inflate,
            Modifier.constrainAs(fragmentIWantToAdd) {
                top.linkTo(section2.bottom)
            }
        )
    }
}
```